# Lambda is sending previous event instead of "live"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm trying to fire a callback when a new EC2 instance is in the "running" state. I've created a Cloudwatch alert and connected it to my Lambda function.

The problem is that the lambda function "is always one instance behind". The first instance I created the lambda does nothing, if I launch a second instance I get the id from the first and so on.

this is my lambda code:

```
const http = require('http');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const instanceId = event['detail']['instance-id'];
    const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

    const params = {
      Filters: [
        {
          Name: "instance-id", 
          Values: [instanceId]
        }
      ]
    };
    const request = getInstanceDetails(params, ec2)

    request.then((tags) => {
      sendTags(tags, instanceId).then((results) => {
        console.log("SUCESS")
        return resolve('END')
      })
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log("Error")
      return resolve('Error')
    })
  })
};

function getInstanceDetails(params, ec2) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error on describing instances")
        return reject('ERROR')
      } else {  
        if (data && data['Reservations'][0] && data['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0] &&  data['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']) {
          const tags = data['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']
          const instanceType = tags.filter((v) => v['Key'] == 'Name' && v['Value'] == 'target-instance')
          if (instanceType.length > 0) {
            return resolve(tags)
          } else {
            console.log('wrong instance type')
            return reject('wrong instance type')
          }
        } else {
          console.log('empty tags')
          return resolve('empty tags')
        }
      }
    });
  })
}

function sendTags(tags, instanceId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      lambda: {
        tags: tags,
        instance_id: instanceId
      } 
    });

    const options = {
      host: '********',
      path: '********',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
      }
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
       res.on('data', function(d) {
         console.log(d);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log('HTTP Error')
      return resolve('HTTP Error');
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
    return resolve('Success');
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't return a Promise in an async lambda. I don't know for sure that that's the problem, but it's not the correct way to do it. `getInstanceDetails` returns a promise, ok. Your handler should do its stuff normally outside of a promise, then `const request = getInstanceDetails(params, ec2)` (etc) should be `const tags = await getInstanceDetails(params, ec2); await sendTags(tags, instanceId); return "SUCCESS";`

Comment: @404 I've removed the promise (leftover code from my testing code). but its still not working :/ do you have any idea on why this would happen?

Comment: I've experienced similar behaviour when I was not using async code correctly. I can't explain why it happens but I know it was due to that. I can post a full answer with the code structured as I think it should be if you want.

Comment: @404 if you can please do, I'm at a loss here. I have a lambda triggered by objects dropping in a S3 bucket and it's working as expected. I just can't seem to get this specific case running properly :)

Comment: I'm not well-versed in mixing promises and callbacks, but it seems like you could replace these two lines -- `req.end();` `return resolve('Success');` -- with one line `req.end( function() {
    resolve('Success'); } );` which would defer resolving the promise until the HTTP request finishes.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot still not working. As I said before I don't mind removing either the promises or callbacks. the code provided by 404 before ditched Promises